# Marker position doesn't move

Tags: android, location, marker

My code

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

the marker added in the `onLocationChanged()` method doesn't move when location changes. however the blue dot does move to the new location..

i would also like to know how to show the current address of the place instead of "current position" text

Comment: remove the marker from map and add again

Comment: no useful i tried that already also i tried to place the code for location update in an else block

Comment: are you calling `requestLocationUpadte()` ?

Comment: my code works fine the location is updated as i clearly mentioned above. however the marker doesnt move to the new location